# change textview background until select another textview in android

Tags: android, selector, textview, android-adapter

I have to develop an android application.

I have using below textview:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/deals"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@drawable/best_deal_bg"
    android:text="Deals"
   />
```

This is background of these textview:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_active" android:state_enabled="true"
      android:state_pressed="true" />
  </selector>
```

Here .,If i have to click these textview means that tiime ly shows background.

But i wish to need the output like.have to shows background until select another textview.

How can i do ?? please give me solution for these ???

**EDIT:**

i have set that background on android textview onclik functionality:

```
deals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deals);
      deals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {

       deals.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.best_deal_bg));
        Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(),Deals.class);
        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("BestDeals",intent);
               }
    });
```

Here am getting below error :

**07-11 10:07:50.593: E/AndroidRuntime(816): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.TextView.setBackground
**

**EDIT:**

```
deals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deals);
      deals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
    View lastclickedview=null;
            if(v != lastclickedview) {
             v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.best_deal_bg));
                 lastclickedview.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.message_icon));
         }
        lastclickedview = v;
      Intent intent = new Intent(getParent(),Deals.class);
        TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
        parentActivity.startChildActivity("BestDeals",intent);
               }
       });
```

Here am getting below error :

**E/AndroidRuntime(883): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.setBackground**

What's worng in my code.pls give me solution for these ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamically change it in your code on selection of another TextView use

```
yourTextView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.best_deal_bg));
```

and if you want remove the background use

```
yourTextView.setBackground(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

first change your textview's background color from your onclickListener and create a view object to save last clicked text view, in second time click on the texview check change the backgound of last clicked view to deafault color

```
textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(v != lastclickedview) {
                    v.setBackground("new color");
                    lastclickedview.setBackground("default");
                }
                //your Action
                lastclickedview = v;
            }
        });
```

Comment: i done like :deals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.deals);
  deals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    View lastclickedview = null;
   if(v != lastclickedview) {v.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.best_deal_bg));    lastclickedview.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.message_icon));
             }
             lastclickedview = v;
          }
  });  but am getting the message :07-11 10:14:58.453: E/AndroidRuntime(883): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.setBackground